# Change from staff to lyrics to chords

Tags: lilypond

What I want to achieve, for example, is to start with a single staff, change to chordmode somewhere, and change to lyrics somewhere later.

Like this:
[image: Changes from staff to chords to lyrics]

The only way, I found, is to use a `\markup` block. But it is cumbersome and does not handle line breaks.

```
\version "2.18.2"

\markup {
  \general-align #Y #CENTER
  { 
    \score { \new Staff { \relative c' { c4 d e f } } \layout {} }
    \hspace #-8
    \score { \new ChordNames { \chordmode { c4 d:m e:m f} } \layout { } }
    \column { \line { "Some text." } }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious. What software or language is this?

Comment: @Karen: Lilypond.

Comment: Yes, lilypond. I put it as a tag. Should I say it in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to ask on the [LilyPond user list.](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user)

You can fiddle around with stuff like

```
\version "2.18.2"

\new Staff \with { \accepts "ChordNames" \accepts "Lyrics" }
{
  \relative c' { c4 d e f }
  \stopStaff
  \chords { c d:m e:m f }
  \lyrics { "Some text." }
}
```

[image: Resulting image]

but once you start having more detailed needs (like adjusting alignment and sizes and other stuff), any solution is going to need a discussion and will turn out so specific to your needs that Stackexchange is the wrong place for it.